# Realm object predicate search is invalid

Tags: swift, realm

Using Realm DB in a swift application. I'm trying to filter the results with a predicate as follows:

```
  class func fetchUsersFromDB(usersId: [String]) -> [User]{
        var users = [User]()
        let realm = Realm()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId IN %@", argumentArray: usersId)
        var allUsers = realm.objects(User).filter(predicate)
        users = Array(allUsers)
        return users
    }
```

But this won't compile. I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'IN clause requires an array of items'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It must be compiling. You are getting a run time exception

Comment: Line number 377, in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMQueryUtil.mm  indicates, there is no support for Swift Array, they don't confirm to NSFastEnumeration..

Comment: Is there another way? Should I loop my query for each strings in the array?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `argumentArray:` label, as with it you're calling the wrong initializer for NSPredicate:

`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId IN %@", usersId)`

Comment: In last XCode version, this doesn't work. I have this error "Missing argument label 'argumentArray:' in call". Do you see the same?

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 3, just use `Array(usersId)` instead of `usersId`.